# Unable to pass string array to the WebApi Actionfilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, action-filter

Based on this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664615(v=vs.71).aspx I can pass single dimension array of primitive types.
However, whenever I am passing a string array I am not getting desired values set against this Custom Action Filter Property. Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true)]
public class CheckModelForNullAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly Func<Dictionary<string, object>, string[],  bool> _validate;
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string[] ExcludeArgs { get; set; }

    public CheckModelForNullAttribute( )
        : this((objects, excludedArgs) => objects.ContainsValue(null) && excludedArgs.Any(objects.ContainsKey) == false)
    {

    }


    public CheckModelForNullAttribute(Func<Dictionary<string, object>, string[], bool> checkCondition)
    {
        _validate = checkCondition;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (_validate(actionContext.ActionArguments, ExcludeArgs))
        {
            actionContext.ModelState.AddModelError("EmptyModel", ErrorMessage);
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, actionContext.ModelState.ValidationErrors(ErrorCode));
        }
    }
}
```

And it is used as:

```
[CheckModelForNullAttribute(ExcludeArgs = new[] { "requests"}, ErrorMessage = Constants.GenericErrors.DefaultError )]
public HttpResponseMessage Create([FromBody] CreateAccountsRequest requests)
{ }
```

On debug when the cursor come over _validate(...) condition the value of string array is blank where as I have a required value in `ErrorMessage` variable. 
[image]

Comment: working fine for me.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh No mate it is not!

Answer (score 1):

My test-

```
[CheckModelForNullAttribute(ExcludeArgs = new string[] { "Test" }, ErrorMessage = "error", ErrorCode = "404")]
```

[image]

Comment: Umm interesting, what is the version of WebApi are you using , I am on webapi 5.2.3 I have also noticed that mine is initiating filter twice i.e. when I put break point on a constructor. because of your great efforts, I will uplift your answer. If you can check with the version that I have mentioned will be probably an answer if there is a bug in latest version release.

Comment: Hi guys. I am facing the same issues with both string and object arrays passing to ActionFilterAttribute for WebApi 5.2.3. Strange thing, that int and double arrays are working fine. Do you have some results of this issue investigation?